# writing on different tag with one ajax function

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am getting information from server about number of likes and dislike using ajax function the queries used :
this for getting number of likes :

```
    $q3="select count(value) as a from rank where personID='$person' and itemID='$itemID' and value>0";
   $result3=mysqli_query($con->getcon(),$q3);
   $row3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
   echo $row3['a'];
```

and this for getting number of dislikes :

```
  $q3="select count(value) as b from rank where personID='$person' and itemID='$itemID' and value<0";
   $result3=mysqli_query($con->getcon(),$q3);
   $row3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
   echo $row3['b'];
```

and this ajax code to get the number of likes :

```
function vote(i,x,id){


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {

  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('up'+i).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "vote.php?id="+id+"&v="+x, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
```

how can I edit it to get the number of likes and dislikes and put them on different tags

Comment: If you need to combine different types of information and have that returned from your php script in an ajax call, you should put it all in an array or object and return it as json. Then you can parse it in javascript and put the different elements where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I aggree jeroen. 
your ajax call should call a php function ("getVotes()") that will return a json array. 
for example, without a lot of rework (could be easily improved ;-) :

```
function getVotes($itemId, $person){

     $q3="select count(value) as a from rank where personID='$person' and itemID='$itemID' and value>0";
       $result3=mysqli_query($con->getcon(),$q3);
       $row3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
       $likes = $row3['a'];

     $q3="select count(value) as a from rank where personID='$person' and itemID='$itemID' and value<0";
       $result3=mysqli_query($con->getcon(),$q3);
       $row3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
       $dislikes = $row3['a'];

       print json_encode(array('dislikes'=> $dislikes,'likes'=> $likes);
}
```